# Creating a component into which other components may be inserted

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm building an Angular 5 "shell" module which I will be using to "wrap" other applications. It will provide a header, footer, sidebar, and an area into which another application can insert its content. I have the header/sidebar done, but I'm not sure how to provide the area into which another application will insert it's content. This module will export a `shell` component which other applications may use. I'd like to be able to import this module into another Angular application and do something like this:

```
<shell>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</shell>
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I accomplish this? Also is it the correct way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your shell.component.ts need to be look like this

```
selector: 'shell',
templateUrl: `<div id="shell"> 
   <ng-content></ng-content> 
</div>`
```

inside your html. Now everything you will add between shell, will replaced inside